# Wildly 9 remote console access

Tags: java, wildfly

My 1st question on this site !  ;-)

I try in vain to access my Wildfly 9 (standalone mode) admin console remotely. It works well locally on the Windows server with Wildfly is installed but no remote access.

There is no problem with the firewall which allows port 9990 and I tried the 2 methods described everywhere on the web to enable remote access:

- `standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0`
- Modify standalone.xml with:

```
  <interface name="management">
        <any-address/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="public">
      <any-address/>
  </interface>
```

Still it does not work !! Any idea ??

JC

Comment: Do you have a user setup? Do you see an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the machine where you Wildfly is running is accepting TCP connections on ports 8080 and 9990 BOTH not 9990 ONLY !!

And for your first solution make sure you stop the server before executing the commande which add parameters that enable remote access from any source (IP/hostname) to the administrative page.

```
cd /opt/wildfly9/bin
./jboss-cli.bat --connect --command=:shutdown
```

Good luck !

Comment: I changed the default Wildfly 8080 port to port 80 but I don't think it has an effect on the console behaviour ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 100% about Wildfly 9 - but the below works in Wildfly 8 & JBoss EAP 7:

Add some new properties to the `<system-properties>` section:

```
<property name="jboss.bind.address" value="1.2.3.4"/>
<property name="jboss.bind.address.management" value="1.2.3.4"/>
<property name="jboss.bind.address.unsecure" value="1.2.3.4"/>
```

And then amend the `<interface>` section like so:

```
<interface name="management">
  <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management}"/>
 </interface>
 <interface name="public">
  <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address}"/>
 </interface>
 <interface name="unsecure">
  <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure}"/>
 </interface>
```

Obviously replacing the IP addresses to those of the machine they are running on. Also, you don't need all of management, public and unsecure, but I just added them for this example.

When you start the server, look at the start up logs and you'll see something like:

> Http management interface listening on http://1.2.3.4:9990/management
>
> Admin console listening on http://1.2.3.4:9990

And then you can use these URLs to access the interface remotely.

Comment: I will try your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the origin of this issue: the proxy on the remote VM was not properly configured.